# User referencing another user causes unexpected error

Tags: 7, entities, users

I have a Drupal 7 site with a bunch of users. Some are clients and others are sellers (role). I put an entity reference field `field_seller` on the user account form which filters users with the seller role.

Now, when applying a seller to a client and the client logs in, he gets an error

> "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

The following error is shown in the log:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be
>   converted to string in _theme_table_cell() (row 2418 of
>   /mysite.com/includes/theme.inc).

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the user entity will be rendered at the profile page. So you should check the settings here: `admin/config/people/accounts/display`

Also you check if the role client is able to access user profiles, if the seller will be rendered on the clients profile page

Comment: Thanks. The render problem was actually in a custom module.